# Field, that specified twice in foreign keys

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have following model.

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    type    = models.CharField(max_length=21, choices=OBJECT_TYPE_CHOICES)
    program = models.ForeignKey(Program, db_column='object_id', to_field='id', null=True, blank=True)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, db_column='object_id', to_field='id', null=True, blank=True)
```

Type field determine, which field (program or article) will be active. But when i try to add comment using Django admin panel, I get error: `"Column 'object_id' specified twice".` I understand why this error occurs, but don't understand how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of behavior isn't supported by Django. Even if you managed to accomplish it, it's a dirty, dirty hack and will result in much cursing at you by any developer that should ever be so unfortunate as to inherit your code.

Use the contenttypes framework, specifically GenericForeignKeys: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you're using the same name for two columns in database, I think you should use this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/contenttypes/